# Android Studio Gradle Build Copy Task

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to copy files before the build starts, but the gradle task dont start.

My section android in my build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

//Copy app_values.xml
task copy_app_values (type: Copy)<<{
    println 'Copy app_values'
    copy_app_values.from  pathtoValues+'app_values.xml'
    copy_app_values.into  projectDir+'/'+moduleName+'/src/main/res/values'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    hockeyapp {
        debuggable true
        println 'Build HockeyApp'
        tasks.add(copy_app_values)
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone explain how this works. I'm newbie in gradle.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure by your question what exactly you are looking for. Either you just want to run this task once before gradle tries to create the hockeyapp build or just before the compile. Either way, try the following,

```
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/doc'
    into 'build/target/doc'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(copyDocs)
}
```

Place this piece of code out of the Android section and try running it. Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I want to call `apply from` from another gradle file?